# Why are my 2 sites on the same server (randomly?) switching PHP versions with PHP-FPM

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm

My issue is as follows:

1 server running Debian 11 in a virtual machine (though I've tested with 9 and 10 and they both show the same behaviour)

with 2 websites both configured to run with php-fpm & apache. Each site has a single index.php file and the contents of those files is `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. 1 site has been set to run php8.0 and the other php8.1, this represents a real world situation that I'm dealing with. This has been set up by including an apache config file into my main apache config file for each site with the contents:

```
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
# Enable http authorization headers
<IfModule setenvif_module>
SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
    <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </If>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".+\.(phps|inc)$">
    # Deny access to raw php sources by default
    # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
    # only in specific virtual host or directory
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
# Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
<FilesMatch "^\.ph(ar|p|ps|tml)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

The config file for php8.1 then uses the php8.1-fpm.sock. ps aux shows the following:

```
root      114787  0.0  0.3 222780 27312 ?        Ss   17:10   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data  114788  0.0  0.5 247140 48664 ?        S    17:10   0:03 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  114789  0.0  0.5 247128 48592 ?        S    17:10   0:03 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  114790  0.0  0.6 247136 48748 ?        S    17:10   0:03 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  114791  0.0  0.5 247128 48676 ?        S    17:10   0:05 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  114792  0.0  0.5 247132 48548 ?        S    17:10   0:04 php-fpm: pool www
root      114802  0.0  0.3 227196 28120 ?        Ss   17:10   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data  114803  0.0  0.3 227764 26744 ?        S    17:10   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  114804  0.0  0.1 227196  8896 ?        S    17:10   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  114805  0.0  0.1 227196  8896 ?        S    17:10   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  114806  0.0  0.1 227196  8896 ?        S    17:10   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

Contents of /etc/php/8.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:

```
[www]

user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = /run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data

pm = dynamic

pm.max_children = 5

pm.start_servers = 2

pm.min_spare_servers = 1

pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

The contents of /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf are exactly the same except that listen is = /run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock

Contents of /etc/php80/apache-include.conf (replace with 81 for php8.1):

```
Alias   /php80 /etc/php80/htdocs
<Directory /etc/php80/htdocs>
    <IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
        Include /etc/php80/etc/php-apache2-fpm.conf
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
<Location  /php80 >
    Options FollowSymLinks
    <IfModule mod_php7.c>
        Include /etc/php80/etc/php-apache2.conf
    </IfModule>
        SetEnv  st_config_filepath /etc/php80/config.ini
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteOptions inherit
        # Maintenance for this installation
        RewriteCond /etc/php80/maintenance -f
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Maintenance_Override
        RewriteRule ^.*$ /maintenance/?  [L,R=307]
    </IfModule>
</Location>    
# Deny access to simplesaml directories    
<DirectoryMatch "^/etc/php80/htdocs/libraries/simplesamlphp/(?!(auth|resources|module.php)).+">
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Contents of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@*.*    
    ServerName ${APACHE_LOCALFQDN}
    ServerAlias ${APACHE_HOSTNAME}    
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/    
    <Directory />
        Options
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>    
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory> 
# Logging

# For proxied requests, log different information:
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" forwarded

# Proxied access log:
    LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" proxy
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${APACHE_LOCALFQDN}-ssl.access-proxy.log proxy env=forwarded
 
# SSL Configuration
SSLEngine on
SSLOptions StdEnvVars OptRenegotiate
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/${APACHE_LOCALFQDN}.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/${APACHE_LOCALFQDN}.key

<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0    
BrowserMatch "MSIE [7-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

################################################################################
# SSL hardening options
#Probably not relevant to show here

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I have a php.sh file in the php80/ and php81 directories:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
. /etc/php80/etc/php-cli.sh

env config_filepath=/etc/php80/config.ini /usr/bin/${PHPVERSION:=php7.3} ${PHPOPTIONS} $*
```

The contents of php-cli.sh is:

```
PHPOPTIONS="-d magic_quotes_gpc=off -d register_globals=off -d safe_mode=off -d session.use_trans_sid=off -d output_buffering=off -d zlib.output_compression=off -d ignore_user_abort=on -d upload_max_filesize=1500M -d post_max_size=1500M -d memory_limit=-1 -d date.timezone=Europe/Berlin"

PHPVERSION="${FORCE_PHP_VERSION:-php8.0}"
```

php81 then has the relevant parts set correctly.

What I really don't understand and where my problem lies is, why when I keep refreshing the individual pages do I sometimes see the 8.0 site showing that it is using php8.1 and vice versa. I sometimes have to refresh the pages 10-20 times before it switches but it never fails to show up sooner rather than later.

How would I go about figuring out why this is happening, or is there something very obvious that I'm missing?

Many thanks in advance!

**Further research/Possible explanations:**

**1.** The php fpm master processes are all running as root and all child processes are running as www-data (as can be seen above in the ps aux output). Initial reading of https://www.binarytides.com/php-fpm-separate-user-uid-linux/ would suggest that it may actually be possible for any pool to be used for a request despite using different sockets since they are all running under the www-data user:

> "Running each site with its own uid/gid is more secure and easier to
> deal with. If all sites ran with same user, then php on one site could
> read/write the files of other users."

**1.1.** <strike>Upon further experimentation I see that changing the name of the pool for either php8.0 or 8.1 is not sufficient to decouple it from the any of the master processes which lends, in my eyes, credibility to the previously referenced article that says that different users/groups also need to be set.[image: screenshot of ps aux | grep php]</strike>

**1.1.1.** Ok scratch that last item, I hadn't cottoned on to ps aux not showing the relationships between processes. ps afx shows that the child processes are correctly assigned. Unfortunate since what I though I had found, I had in fact not.

```
 161186 ?        Ss     0:01 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
 161191 ?        S      0:10  \_ php-fpm: pool php80
 161192 ?        S      0:11  \_ php-fpm: pool php80
 161193 ?        S      0:07  \_ php-fpm: pool php80
 161205 ?        Ss     0:01 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
 161206 ?        S      0:00  \_ php-fpm: pool www
 161207 ?        S      0:00  \_ php-fpm: pool www
```

**I have now tested setting a different user and group and still see the same behaviour**

**2.** It seems this issue has actually [been encountered before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316859/php-fpm-working-but-ignoring-version-from-sethandler).

> Tried phpinfo() page and got PHP 7.4.15 instead of expected 5.6.40. We did the same with a 7.3 and got the same 7.4 on phpinfo() using SetHandler of php7.3 as well.

The solution presented (move away from linux sockets and use network communication instead) I have tested and can confirm as working. It is unfortunately not an ideal solution and doesn't explain why using sockets doesn't work as it should. The solution involving `<If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">` I already had present anyway and has no effect.

**3.** I have found 2 further systems that we have set up which use Debian 10.12 and Apache 2.4.54 (as opposed to apache 2.4.53 as in the example above), and Debian 11.4 and Apache 2.4.54. For those systems we use .htaccess files instead of individual Apache configs per site, **the issue issue is not reproducible under these conditions**

Comment: Could you show longer snippet of the configuration context? It is unclear if this configuration is on a virtual host level or some other context.

Comment: I've added more configs, let me know if you need anything else specifically

Comment: what kind of websites are those? are they executing php-cli somewhere?

Comment: @Orphans They are! I have added details to the main question.

Can you explain what you mean by "what kind of websites are those?"

Comment: @Oceanic_Panda Well, I can't really see anything that could explain how a VirtualHost could "switch php-version back and forth" here at all. I frankly sounds impossible with this setup. However - if you execute "php --version" on your server, you'll see the version number of the latest one. So I wonder if there anything on your website or cronjobs that is just executing the "php" binary instead of specifying version (as recommended).

Comment: @Orphans see my latest edit (possible solution 2)